# A locomotive accelerates a train of identical railway carts. Plz refer to the body for the question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

This question really puzzled me!! How to solve someone help! 
"A locomotive accelerates a train of identical railway carts. The carts are numbered consecutively with the cart next to locomotive having the number 1. The tension in the connection between the carts with numbers 4 and 5 is three times bigger than the tension in the connection between the carts with numbers 14 and 15. What is the number of the last cart? there is no resistance to the train's motion." Plz explain the answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The tension in each coupling is proportional to the number of carts behind the coupling. This is because the tension must be sufficient to accelerate all the carts behind the coupling at the same acceleration as the train, but the mass of the carts behind the coupling depends on how many carts there are.